# What is the meaning of "Failed building wheel for flask-mysqldb" in pip3 install?

Tags: python, pip, flask-mysql

I have a MacBook Air with macOs Sonoma 14.0 and when I write in the terminal

```
$ pip3 install flask-mysqldb
```

I get the error:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11082165). Please include the complete error message and traceback in your question as formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a very new version Python (3.12, released just this month) that `mysqlclient` (a dependency of the distribution you're trying to install) does not yet provide pre-built wheels for.

Because of this, `pip` is trying to build `mysqlclient` from  source. This is fails because you're missing some required system dependencies.

You can consult `mysqlclient`'s documentation for its exact build dependencies. At a minimum, you'll need to install `pkg-config` based on that error message.

Alternatively, you can switch to a version of Python that `msqlclient` supports and provides wheels for. Currently, that's Python 3.8 - 3.11 for `mysqlclient` v2.2.0.